# How to get IGrouping index with Linq to entities ? (NotSupportedException)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, notsupportedexception

I'm using `EF` code first, and I'm trying to create a query which would get a player's rank based on a particular column, here `Seniority`.
Here is an example of what could be the `Players` table (`Rank` is not part of it, I need to deduce it from `Seniority`):

```
Username | Seniority (=> Rank)  
player1  | 25        (=> 1st)  
player2  | 20        (=> 2nd)  
player3  | 20        (=> 2nd)  
player4  | 18        (=> 3rd)  
player5  | 16        (=> 4th)  
player6  | 16        (=> 4th)  
player7  | 15        (=> 5th)  
player8  | 11        (=> 6th)  
player9  | 10        (=> 7th)  
player10 | 8         (=> 8th)  
player11 | 7         (=> 9th)  
player12 | 5         (=> 10th)  
player13 | 2         (=> 11th)  
player14 | 1         (=> 12th)  
player15 | 0         (=> 13th)
```

I would need the following request to return all players whose rank is <= 10 (i.e. from player1 to player12), and then paginate this; for instance the first page with 10 max elements per page (i.e. from player1 to player10).

```
entities.Players
.GroupBy(p => p.Seniority)
.Where((group, groupIndex) => groupIndex <= 10)
.SelectMany((group, groupIndex) =>
    group.Select(grp =>
        new PlayerRanking()
        {
            Player = grp,
            Rank = groupIndex + 1,
            Score = grp.Seniority
        }
    )
    .OrderByDescending(r => r.Score)
    .ThenBy(r => r.Player.UserName)
)
.ToPagedList(pageNb, 10);
```

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Models.BO.Ranking.PlayerRanking] SelectMany[IGrouping`2,PlayerRanking](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.Int32,Models.BO.Players.Player]], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`3[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.Int32,Models.BO.Players.Player],System.Int32,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Models.BO.Ranking.PlayerRanking]]])', and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

I read on some other posts that `EF` is complaining about `Where` and `SelectMany` having two arguments, but could I do without ?
I don't want to use `ToList()` nor `AsEnumerable()` because if I do, I guess the request will enumerate all `Players` entries (which can be really huge...) although I only need 10 of them. I really care about performances on this particular query.

Is there a way ?

Thanks a lot.

***@octavioccl***

I just added the `Skip` part for pagination:

```
var result = entities.Players.GroupBy(p => p.Seniority)
                       .OrderBy(e=>e.Key)
                       .Skip((pageNb - 1) * 10)
                       .Take(10)
                       .AsEnumerable()
                       .SelectMany((g,i)=>g.OrderBy(e=>e.UserName)
                                            .Select(e=>new PlayerRanking()
                                                       {
                                                          Player = e,
                                                          Rank = i + 1,
                                                          Score = e.Seniority
                                                       });
```

For `pageNb = 1`, the result seems correct, I have player1 to player10 with correct ranks :)
However for `pageNb = 2` the Rank restarts from 1 again (i.e. player11 is marked as 1st instead of 9th).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linq to Entities does not support method overloads with `index`. Also, since any usage of `GroupBy` returning sequence (and not simply keys + aggregates as in SQL `GROUP BY`) leads to 2 table access paths in the generated SQL, you could simply do that manually and use `Count` method for determining the rank (which should be the count of distinct `Seniority` values greater than the current).

So the working equivalent of your query could be like this:

```
var result = entities.Players
    .Select(p => new PlayerRanking
    {
        Player = p,
        Rank = entities.Players.Where(p1 => p1.Seniority > p.Seniority)
               .Select(p1 => p1.Seniority).Distinct().Count() + 1,
        Score = p.Seniority
    })
    .Where(r => r.Rank <= 10)
    .OrderBy(r => r.Rank)
    .ThenBy(r => r.Player.UserName)
    .ToPagedList(pageNb, 10);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works like a charm ! One more time, you made my day and I learned some thing :D

Comment: You are welcome. All your questions are interesting and challenging :) Unfortunately nothing can beat SQL [`OVER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) clause, but simply there is no equivalent LINQ / EF construct. If you have performance issues, you can always resort to raw SQL :)

Comment: Did not know about the `OVER` clause, seems pretty cool indeed, I'll definitely use it if necessary ! Since the app does not have real users yet I can not be sure about performances but at least I try to think about it while developping. Although this might not be directly linked to this question, I'd say a real thank you because you spend a lot of time helping people, including me ;)